# No output from php unless there is a "?>"

Tags: php

I just installed php locally on my pc to debug an error. To my surprise I got no output at all from my php-script. So I tested this (temp.php):

```
<?php
   echo "hi"
```

I ran this with `php temp.php`. No output. Confused. Added "?>"

```
<?php
   echo "hi"
?>
```

Now I got the expected output. What is going on there? Is not the recommendation to leave out the final `?>`?

Comment: You forgot to add a semicolon at the end of `echo "hi"`.

Comment: Just a comment: I do not really understand why people do not use the `?>`

Comment: The `;` acts as a pointer for PHP to say, ok... nothing else after this, echo it. However, if you omit that and don't add the end tag that also being an ending pointer, it will throw an error, because it expects and awaiting more/further instructions. However, this is valid `<?php echo "hi"; echo "thanks" ?>` - The last echo does not need a semi-colon, if there is a closing `?>` tag.

Comment: I think its just because it's something extra. I still use '?>'

Comment: @Guilherme it can be useful to avoid the closing tag if you are, for example, [writing a WordPress plugin](http://hardcorewp.com/2013/always-omit-closing-php-tags-in-wordpress-plugins/).

Comment: @TomFenech As I understand the "advantage" is to avoid whitespaces ... It seems as useful. +1 for you.

Comment: Thanks @Korikulum and @David Corbin. So it works with just a `;` and no `?>`.